# Как создать авторизацию Windows-приложения для сайта

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

Есть сайт на ASP.Net 6 с авторизацией на ASP.Net Identity 3.0. Есть Windows-приложение на .Net 6. Нужно чтобы с приложения пользователь ввёл логин и пароль и получил настройки профиля + некоторые данные с БД для пользователя на сайте. Как это можно сделать. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 03.10.2022:**
Решил создать отдельный сервер авторизации для своих личных проектов (спасибо товарищу Andrei Brizhak!)

У меня есть классы пользователя

```
    public sealed class SiteUser: IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    
        #region Базовые настройки
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Имя пользователя
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Фамилия пользователя
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Пол пользователя
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public UserGender Gender { get; set; } = UserGender.SexMale;
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Дата рождения пользователя
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public DateTime BirthdayDate { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Расположение пользователя, например, "Белгород, Россия"
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public string? UserLocation { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Аватар пользователя
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public byte[]? Avatar { get; set; }
    
        #endregion
    
        #region Чёрный список
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Чёрный список пользователей
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public string? BlackList { get; set; }
    
        #endregion
    
        #region Meta-данные
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Адрес IP последнего входа пользователя
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public string? LastIP { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Дата регистрации пользователя
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Дата последнего входа пользователя на сайт
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Предыдущий никнейм
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public string? PreviousNickName { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Дата смены никнейма
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public DateTime NickNameChangeDate { get; set; }
    
        #endregion
    
        #region Приватность и соцсети
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Настройки приватности аккаунта
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public Guid Privacy { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// СоцCети аккаунта
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public Guid SocNets { get; set; }
    
        #endregion
    
        #region Форум
        /// <summary>
        /// Подпись для форума
        /// </summary>
        [PersonalData]
        public string? ForumSignature { get; set; }
        #endregion
    
        #region Удаление пользователя
        /// <summary>
        /// Маркировка удалённого пользователя
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Дата удаления пользователя
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime DeletedAtDate { get; set; }
        #endregion
    
        #region Настройка темы
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Имя темы
        /// </summary>
        public string? ThemeName { get; set; }
    
        #endregion
    }
```

и группы пользователя

```
public sealed class SiteRole: IdentityRole<Guid>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Отображаемое имя роли
    /// </summary>
    public string? RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

Возможно (и где почитать!) это сделать или нет?

Comment: JWT вам в помощь

Answer (score 2):

JWT или куки.
Механизм описан, например, [здесь (см. главу 13)](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet6/)

Вкратце можно так:

1. В приложении wpf cоздаем объект HttpWebRequest, методом POST шлем логин и пароль
2. Веб-приложение получает данные; проверяет, есть ли такой пользователь в базе данных (ну или где-то там, где у Вас хранятся креды пользователей); проверяет права пользователя
3. Веб-приложение устанавливает аутентификационные куки, шлет их пользователю
4. Wpf-клиент при следующих обращениях к веб-приложению прикручивает полученные куки к запросу. Так веб-приложение поймет, что к нему летят запросы от авторизованного пользователя (пользователя, прошедшего аутентификацию и авторизацию).

Вообще тоже самое может происходить, когда Вы просто входите в свое веб-приложение из браузера. По сути, веб-приложению нет разницы, откуда получать креды по POST - из формы html или из свойств классов wpf-приложения.

P.S. Знаю, мое сообщение не тянет на полноценный ответ. Но, думаю, нет смысла переписывать сюда то, что уже описано в интернете. Я бы просто написал комментарий, да не хватает у меня привилегий, чтобы писать комменты :)

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` - устарел уже очень давно, не стоит его советовать. JWT и Куки - это, по сути, две разные вещи, где первое, это токен авторизации, который может быть отправлен любым образом, а куки - это место хранения токенов, один из способов передачи. Далее, при чем тут WPF? В вопросе вроде и слова про это нет. Ну и JWT, если его брать в расчет, то он куда сложнее, чем просто дать токен и его использовать, ибо там зачастую 2 токена (рефреш, и асесс), чтоб постоянно не вводить лог и пасс (и вообще их не хранить). Ну и также, это все так называемые API, о которых стоит упомянуть.

Comment: Да. Увидел в вопросе "Windows-приложение" и сразу вообразил себе wpf. Сорри :)
Просто описал способ, который сам когда-то использовал.
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Identity используется для авторизации пользователей,  но только Web приложений на платформе ASP.NET. Если Вам нужно хранить данные о пользователях в отдельном приложении для идентификации пользователей, то для этого есть [Duende Identity Server](https://duendesoftware.com/products/identityserver) . Он условно бесплатный, если ваша компания не зарабатывает более миллиона долларов в год))).  При этом Identity Server предоставляет Ресурсы для Идентификации.  Клиентом для этого сервиса могут быть любые веб-приложения (включая ASP.NET, JS-фреймворки, ванильный HTML и JS), мобильные приложения, или десктопные приложения. [Вот здесь](https://youtu.be/nF7lM6V1yOE) немного теории на русском языке об этом.

Comment: А есть ли документация для сего чуда?

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду под "чудом" - Duende Identity Server, то по указанной выше ссылке, вы можете найти документацию,  естественно  на английском языке.

Comment: А возможно ли задействовать в Duende Identity Server нестандартные классы (см. вложение)?

Comment: В Identity Server, есть свои стандаратные настройки для пользователей  IdentityUser, можно создать свой класс наследуемый от IdentityUser, с произвольными настройками.